# How can I run all methods of an external class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class "RSTRule", which has several methods and all the methods start with "generate".
In another class "RSTRules" i want to execute all methods in "RSTRule"  with a for loop  in it's constructor. I have written the following code but i do not know how do i excute these methods and how do i invoke them,?

```
public class RSTRules extends ArrayList<RSTRule>  {

public RSTRules(){
    Class<?> rstRule = Class.forName("RSTRule");
    Method[] methods = rstRule.getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
           if (m.getName().startsWith("generate")) {
            //Run the method m 
           }
        }

}
```

also this is a method from the class "RSTRule"

```
public RSTRule generateBothNotSatisfy_Join(){
        this.discourseRelation=DiscourseRelation.Join;
        this.nucleus=new NucleusSatelliteInRSTRule("Both_Not_Satisfy_User_Desires_in",propNuc);
        this.satellite=new NucleusSatelliteInRSTRule("Both_Not_Satisfy_User_Desires_in",propSat);
        this.ruleName="BothNotSatisfy_Join";
        this.condition=null;
        this.heuristic=10;
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Class is metaClass in Java (Class describing other class). So you can't invoke method on it. To invoke method you need living instance of class you want to invoke methods of.

Here is a little generic example:

```
    Method[] methods = Object.class.getMethods();
    Object o = new Object();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        method.invoke(o, {params for method});
    }
```

Invoke method takes two parameters. First is instance on which you want to invoke method, and second are parameters for method. (null if method doesn't take any)

Answer (score 0):

```
public RSTRules(){
    Class<?> rstRule = Class.forName("RSTRule");
    Method[] methods = rstRule.getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
           if (m.getName().startsWith(" generate")) {
                method.invoke(rstRule, {params for method}); 
           }
        }

}
```

For details, please refer to the following link

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html